# Unit testing background threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, background

How do you test background threads like this?

As the fetching of the kinect sensor could be a very time-consuming task. I create a task that calls Parallel to fetch the two things-kinect sensor and mcu. If either one is done, the UI will change the string (for both could be done first). It seems really hard to test for you cannot create a new kinectsensor, you can just get one from the KinectSensor.KinectSensors, I tried to simulate the delay so that I can check if the string has changed.

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;

                // while haven't got the sensor, keep fetching
                while (kinectSensor == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    kinectSensor = (from sensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors
                                    where sensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected
                                    select sensor).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                _kinectService = new KinectService(kinectSensor);
                _kinectService.SetupKinectSensor(new EventHandler<ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(ColorImageFrameReadyEventHandler),
                    new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(SkeletonFrameReadyEventHandler));

                DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                {
                    StatusDescription = "Kinect Has connected";
                });
            }, () =>
            {
                IMCU mcu = null;

                while (mcu == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    // get mcu here
                }

                _mcuService = new MCUService(mcu);

                DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                {
                    StatusDescription = "MCU Has connected";
                });
            });

            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            {
                CameraShadowColor = "#FF66B034";
                StatusColor = "#FF66B034";
                StatusCaption = "Ready";
                StatusDescription = "Ready to go";
                ButtonString = "OK";
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Normally you don't unit test stuff like that. That would be integration testing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to implement TDD in this application. If you don't need to test such code, it means there will be no unit test code for this, which against TDD-Write test and use test to help you complete code. Or I'm just doing wrong about TDD?